# Why are my tile improvements taking too many turns to build?

Tags: civilization-5

For some reason it takes around 600 turns to build a single farm. Why is this happening?  How can I fix or improve it?

My settings are: standard pace, level 3 difficulty.

Comment: Are you perhaps currently in the Revolution status?

Comment: @SaintWacko That's the only thing I can think of, though I haven't seen Revolutions in ages since BNW removes them.

Comment: Does this happen on other saves, or is it only this particular run?

Comment: Could be a bug. Sometimes the workers get stuck and you need to manually select them and tell them to build the improvement again. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three possible reasons for this:

**1) You are in revolt** 
You didn't mention which (if any) expansions you're using - but in the past if your civ was in revolt, production and even worker ability would plummet to the point where they're basically useless.

**Solution:** Gain happiness and take your city out of revolt.

**2) Worker Bug**
This bug still exists. If you place your worker on auto, often times they will do very buggy things - especially if you're a civ with custom tile improvements (ex: terrance farm). Sometimes they just run back and forth between two tiles, other times they take 2 turns to build a farm, then cancel it and take two turns to build a trading post - and they repeat this for hundreds of years.

**Solution:** Don't put your workers on auto. Or, if you really want to put them on auto - make sure they're doing their jobs!

**3) Other Bug**
Despite Civ Vs popularity and many patches, there are still a number of bugs that occur.

**Solution:** The best thing you can do is try and do some self-troubleshooting. In your case, I would begin by checking the status of your worker each turn. By selecting the worker as he's making a farm, it will tell you how many turns remaining it will take to build the farm. Is that number changing each turn? Try to narrow down the problem, and maybe you can find a solution with the info you gather!